# How to check remove image? I can not check because before save averter.present? return true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5

I use [carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave: Classier solution for file uploads for Rails, Sinatra and other Ruby web frameworks](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave).

```
@foo.assign_attributes(update_params) #=> update_params includes "remove_avatar"=>"1"
@foo.avatar.present? #=> true
@foo.save
@foo.avatar.present? #=> false
```

before save `present?` return `true`. after save `present?` return `false`.

My Validation

```
validate :validate_avatar

def validate_avatar
  # if @foo.avatar deleted and same conditions, add error
end
```

In `validate_avatar`, `@foo.avatar.present?` is `true` because before save.

I try `after_save :validate_avatar`.

```
after_save :validate_avatar

def validate_avatar
  # if @foo.avatar deleted and same conditions, add error
  # then return false
end
```

Because after_save, `@foo.avatar.present?` is `false`. But `Rails5` not rollback with return `false`.

How to check `@foo.avatar` deleted in validation?

I want to check `avatar` was deleted but remain image crop data. So I need check `@foo.avater` deleted or not delete.
If `avatar` deleted, image crop data deleted too. So check in validation.

Already made a method for delete all image crop data(`xxx_crop` columns) in my project.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to raise an error whenever someone tries to delete their avatar but keep the same parameters everywhere else?

Comment: @bkunzi01 I add the purpose of validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `remove_avatar?`.

`@foo.remove_avatar? #=> true or false`.

- the avatar image will remove if `true` with `save`
- the avatar image will not remove if `false` with `save`

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can do

```
if @foo.save
  <do whatever>
else
  render json: @foo.errors
```

so @foo will have an errors attribute.